# How to select the first row of each group?

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
 ID |  Val   |  Kind
----------------------
 1  |  1337  |   2
 2  |  1337  |   1
 3  |   3    |   4
 4  |   3    |   4
```

I want to make a `SELECT` that will return just the first row for each `Val`, ordering by `Kind`.

Sample output:

```
 ID |  Val   |  Kind
----------------------
 2  |  1337  |   1
 3  |   3    |   4
```

How can I build this query?

Comment: why 3|3|4 and not 4|3|4 - what is the tie-break or do you not care?

Comment: @JackDouglas Actually I have a `ORDER BY ID DESC`, but that is not relevant for the question. In this example I do not care.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This solution also uses `keep`, but `val` and `kind` can also be simply calculated for each group without a subquery:

> ```
> select min(id) keep(dense_rank first order by kind) id
>      , val
>      , min(kind) kind
>   from mytable
>  group by val;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID |  VAL | KIND
> -: | ---: | ---:
>  3 |    3 |    4
>  2 | 1337 |    1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3db08df2d9b684302b9460a818b35d8c)*

KEEP…FIRST and KEEP…LAST are an Oracle-specific feature of aggregates — you can read about then [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) in the Oracle docs, or [on ORACLE_BASE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions#first_and_last):

> The FIRST and LAST functions can be used to return the first or last value from an ordered sequence

Answer (score 80):

Use a [common table expression](http://www.morganslibrary.com/reference/with.html) (CTE) and a windowing/ranking/partitioning function like [ROW_NUMBER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

This query will create an in-memory table called ORDERED and add an additional column of rn which is a sequence of numbers from 1 to N. The [PARTITION BY](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/row_number.html) indicates it should restart at 1 every time the value of Val changes and we want to order rows by the smallest value of Kind.

```
WITH ORDERED AS
(
SELECT
    ID
,   Val
,   kind
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY Kind ASC) AS rn
FROM
    mytable
)
SELECT
    ID
,   Val
,   Kind
FROM
    ORDERED
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

The above approach should work with any RDBMS that has implemented the ROW_NUMBER() function. Oracle has some elegant functionality as expressed in [mik's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6388/2131) that will generally yield better performance than this answer.

Answer (score 28):

bilinkc's solution works fine, but I thought I'd toss mine out as well.  It has the same cost, but might be faster (or slower, I haven't tested it).  The difference is that it uses the First_Value instead of Row_Number.  Since we are only interested in the first value, in my mind it is more straightforward.

```
SELECT ID, Val, Kind FROM
(
   SELECT First_Value(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY Kind) First, ID, Val, Kind 
   FROM mytable
)
WHERE ID = First;
```

Test Data.

```
--drop table mytable;
create table mytable (ID Number(5) Primary Key, Val Number(5), Kind Number(5));

insert into mytable values (1,1337,2);
insert into mytable values (2,1337,1);
insert into mytable values (3,3,4);
insert into mytable values (4,3,4);
```

If you prefer, here is the CTE equivalent.

```
WITH FirstIDentified AS (
   SELECT First_Value(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY Kind) First, ID, Val, Kind 
   FROM mytable
   )
SELECT ID, Val, Kind FROM FirstIdentified
WHERE ID = First;
```

Comment: +1 but I just thought it worth emphasising that your answer and billinkc's are not logically the same unless `id` is unique.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `keep` to select an `id` from each group:

> ```
> select *
> from mytable
> where id in ( select min(id) keep (dense_rank first order by kind, id)
>               from mytable
>               group by val );
> ```
>
> ```
> ID |  VAL | KIND
> -: | ---: | ---:
>  2 | 1337 |    1
>  3 |    3 |    4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78d2ddce35d381f7f49c8c98d7bf2987)*

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MIN(MyTable01.Id) as Id,
       MyTable01.Val     as Val,
       MyTable01.Kind    as Kind 
  FROM MyTable MyTable01,                         
       (SELECT Val,MIN(Kind) as Kind
          FROM MyTable                   
      GROUP BY Val) MyTableGroup
WHERE MyTable01.Val  = MyTableGroup.Val
  AND MyTable01.Kind = MyTableGroup.Kind
GROUP BY MyTable01.Val,MyTable01.Kind
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: That will be a lot less efficient than the other answers due to the fact that two scans over MyTable are needed.

Comment: That's only true if the optimizer takes the written query literally. More advanced optimizers can see the intent (row per group) and produce a plan with a single table access.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from (
    select t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY Val desc) as seqnum 
    from tablename t1
) 
where seqnum=1;
```