# Limiting the number of records from nested INNER JOIN table

Tags: postgresql, join, limits

The context is as follows:

- We have 3 tables: We'll call them A,B and C.
- A has a foreign key referencing table B, we'll call it "bId". The relationship is a ManyToOne. (One record in B can be linked to multiple ones in A, but each record in A is linked to exactly one in B)
- B has a foreign key referencing table C, we'll call it "cId". Same as before, the relationship is ManyToOne One record in C can be linked to multiple ones in B, but each record in B is linked to exactly one in C).

Now, the problem is as follows: Until now, to correlate information between these 3 tables I used a query of the form
`A inner join B inner join C WHERE b.someField = 'x' AND a.otherField = 'y'`, and then processed the aggregated information using a programming language.

My question is, is it possible to limit the number of entries from the table C?

Let's say that C has a field called name, and I only want the data from the first 3 C values, alphabetically. A problem similar to mine seems to be the one answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120842/limiting-rows-from-a-joined-table), but I don't see how to generalise the solution.

To be clear, I don't want to limit the number of records in general, just the ones from the third table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will do so in future questions. But it seems that John K. N. 's answer provides such a context and a solution that achieves what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small example of how this could be achieved.

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.otherfield, 
       B.id, 
       B.somefield, 
       C.id, 
       C.name
FROM   A 
     JOIN B
         ON A.bid  = B.id
     JOIN C
         ON B.cid  = C.id

AND   b.someField  = 'x' 
AND   a.otherField = 'y'
AND   C.name IN 
    (
      SELECT C.name 
      FROM C 
      ORDER BY C.name DESC 
      LIMIT 3
    )
;
```

Example tables and data together with the statement for this answer can be found over on [db<>fiddle (PostgreSQL 14)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=594e39d15c91bd41ffd466a12b4e42ec).

Reproduced here in full:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A (id int, bid int, otherField varchar(10));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE B (id int, cid int, someField varchar(10));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE C (id int, AName varchar(10));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO C 
> (id, AName)
> VALUES 
> (1, 'FirstName'),
> (2, 'SecondName'),
> (3, 'ThirdName'), 
> (4, 'FourthName')
> ;
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO B 
> (id, cid, someField) 
> VALUES (1,1,'x'),
> (1,2,'x'),
> (1,3,'x'),
> (1,4,'x'),
> (2,1,'x'),
> (2,2,'x'),
> (2,3,'y'),
> (2,4,'y'),
> (3,1,'x'),
> (3,2,'z'),
> (3,3,'y'),
> (3,4,'y'),
> (4,1,'y'),
> (4,2,'x'),
> (4,3,'x'),
> (4,4,'x')
> ;
> ```

16 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO A 
> (id,bid,otherField) 
> VALUES
> (1,1,'x'),
> (1,2,'x'),
> (1,3,'x'),
> (1,4,'x'),
> (2,1,'x'),
> (2,2,'x'),
> (2,3,'y'),
> (2,4,'y'),
> (3,1,'x'),
> (3,2,'z'),
> (3,3,'y'),
> (3,4,'y'),
> (4,1,'y'),
> (4,2,'x'),
> (4,3,'x'),
> (4,4,'x')
> ;
> ```

16 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT A.id, 
>        A.otherField, 
>        B.id, 
>        B.someField, 
>        C.id, 
>        C.AName
> FROM   A 
>      JOIN B
>          ON A.bid  = B.id
>      JOIN C
>          ON B.cid  = C.id
>
> AND   b.someField  = 'x' 
> AND   a.otherField = 'y'
> AND   C.AName IN 
>     (
>       SELECT C.AName 
>       FROM C 
>       ORDER BY C.AName DESC 
>       LIMIT 3
>     )
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | otherfield | id | somefield | id | aname     
> -: | :--------- | -: | :-------- | -: | :---------
>  2 | y          |  4 | x         |  2 | SecondName
>  2 | y          |  4 | x         |  3 | ThirdName 
>  2 | y          |  4 | x         |  4 | FourthName
>  3 | y          |  4 | x         |  2 | SecondName
>  3 | y          |  4 | x         |  3 | ThirdName 
>  3 | y          |  4 | x         |  4 | FourthName
>  4 | y          |  1 | x         |  2 | SecondName
>  4 | y          |  1 | x         |  3 | ThirdName 
>  4 | y          |  1 | x         |  4 | FourthName
> ```