# Equivalent idioms in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery

I was reading this article that is about [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/):

> [Exploring a powerful SQL pattern: ARRAY_AGG, STRUCT and UNNEST](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/exploring-a-powerful-sql-pattern-array-agg-struct-and-unnest-b7dcc6263e36)

They use a couple of functions that I am trying to figure out what the Oracle equivalents are, if they even exist.

I am digging through the Oracle documentation and I found something similar to [`ARRAY_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) in Oracle called `LISTAGG`.

What I have not been able to find are the idiomatic equivalents of [`STRUCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring-a-struct-type) and [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest).

#### Are there things that do the same thing as [`STRUCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring-a-struct-type) and [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) or will I have to write my own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Technique Translation

The technique for solving a problem in one RDBMS doesn't always translate well into another.

I've had performance problems with similar code to that which was in the article.  Thus, my comment "This technique will kill performance in Oracle".

I don't see `CAST(MULTISET())` (Oracle's version of `ARRAY_AGG`) being used too much.  As such, the code might be unmaintainable by your replacement after you get a promotion.

## Translating Terms

Translation goes like this

- `STRUCT` in BigData is `TYPE` in Oracle
- `ARRAY_AGG` in BigData is `CAST(MULTISET())` in Oracle
- `UNNEST` in BigData is `TABLE()` in Oracle
- `UNNEST` of XML Data is `XMLTABLE()` in Oracle
- `UNNEST` of JSON Data is `JSON_TABLE()` in Oracle (12c+)

You can't create the structure on the fly.  You have to define it ahead of time.

## EXAMPLES

Creating a structure of a single row:

```
create type emp_t as object (
  EMPNO             NUMBER(4),    
  ENAME             VARCHAR2(10) ,
  JOB               VARCHAR2(9)  ,
  MGR               NUMBER(4)    ,
  HIREDATE          DATE         ,
  SAL               NUMBER(7,2)  ,
  COMM              NUMBER(7,2)  ,
  DEPTNO            NUMBER(2)  
);
/
```

Creating a structure of a set of rows based on above: ( `nested table` )

```
create type emp_tt as table of emp_t;
/
```

Using `CAST(MULTISET())`

```
select d.deptno
  ,cast(multiset(
           select * from scott.emp e where e.deptno=d.deptno
        ) as emp_tt) as emp_table
from dept d
;
```

Using `TABLE()`

```
with data as (
  select d.deptno
    ,cast(multiset(
             select * from scott.emp e where e.deptno=d.deptno
           ) as emp_tt) AS emp_table
  from dept d
)
select b.*
from data a, table( a.emp_table ) b
order by empno;
```

## Oracle's Solution

Business Requirement:  I want the first time a hurricane reached its maximum category along with its position.

Other, inferred, identifiers to "GROUP BY" would be season, basin, subbasin in addition to hurricane name.

One method to solve this in Oracle is to use Analytics.

Since I don't have access to the huricane data, I'll have to improvise.

```
  select deptno as hurricane_name
        ,2017   as season
        ,'NA'   as basin
        ,'WP'   as subbasin
        ,sal    as category
        ,ename  as position
        ,rownum as time
  from scott.emp
```

First thing we do is use the analytic function `RANK()` to rank all of the rows by `category` (descending) and `time` (ascending) but partition the rankings by `season`, `basin`, `subbasin`, and `hurricane_name`

```
  select h.*
    ,RANK() over (partition by season, basin, subbasin, huricane_name
                  order by category desc, time)
      as rank_score
  from huricane_data h
```

Finally, we'll pick only the best (rank_score=1)

```
select *
from analyized_data
where rank_score=1
order by season, basin, subbasin, hurricane_name, time
```

Putting it all together

```
with hurricane_data as (
  select deptno as hurricane_name
        ,2017   as season
        ,'NA'   as basin
        ,'WP'   as subbasin
        ,sal    as category
        ,ename  as position
        ,rownum as time
  from scott.emp
), analyized_data as (
  select h.*
    ,RANK() over (partition by season, basin, subbasin, hurricane_name
                  order by category desc, time) rank_score
  from hurricane_data h
)
select *
from analyized_data
where rank_score=1
-- place season/basin/subbasin filters here
order by season, basin, subbasin, hurricane_name, time;
```

Comment: thanks for the in depth explanation, I just wanted to understand how it would work, I have a similar rollup calculation that I wanted to experiment with. It does not have a huge dataset, probably never will it is weekly data for a few thousand things. I thought this approach might be easier to maintain than what I have now with a bunch of `LEAD` and `LAG` stuff that is completely unmaintainable.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - without knowing your actual problem, I suggest you take a look at 12c's `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.  I used it in a recent answer here:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205530/select-distinct-id-with-max-date-according-to-department/205598#205598

Comment: @Jarrod `LAG` and `LEAD` and windowing functions in general are awesome and quintessentially idiomatic to Oracle. Much better to get familiar with the native idioms that try and import from elsewhere, there is so much pain down that route.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @JackDouglas. I deal Oracle, Informix, SQL Server, DB2, Terradata, MySQL, Mongo, Cassandra, and more on a daily basis. It is really hard to keep up with what is idiomatic for every one of the servers.