# Get one row between two duplicate rows with one different value in a column

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with data entered manually by the customer, there are some data which is duplicated but just a value in one column is different. For example

```
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| Title      | start | end   | Location  |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| Title - abc| 10:00 | 10:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - def| 10:00 | 10:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - abc| 11:00 | 11:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - def| 11:00 | 11:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - ghi| 12:00 | 12:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - jkl| 13:00 | 13:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - mno| 14:00 | 14:30  | Loc1     |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| Title      | start | end   | Location  |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| Title - abc| 10:00 | 10:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - abc| 11:00 | 11:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - ghi| 12:00 | 12:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - jkl| 13:00 | 13:30  | Loc1     |
| Title - mno| 14:00 | 14:30  | Loc1     |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

I want any one row it can be *Title - abc* or *Title - def* Can anyone please help me which this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the first row of each group?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of where [`Analytic functions`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions) can shine! In this case, you have a choice between the [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions) function (also its "mirror image" - LAST_VALUE()) and the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/row_number-analytic-function) function! [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on) gave me the idea for using `FIRST/LAST_VALUE` to emulate  PostgreSQL's [`DISTINCT ON`](https://zaiste.net/postgresql_distinct_on/). See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=004c8fff07e5359ac597fd6d8b9d0b3c)!

### Create and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab
(
  title VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  end_time   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  location    VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (title, start_time, end_time, location),
  CONSTRAINT my_tab_st_lt_et_ck CHECK (start_time < end_time)
);
```

populate (sample):

```
INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES 
(
  'Title - abc', 
  TO_DATE('2020-03-18 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
  TO_DATE('2020-03-18 10:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
  'Loc1'
);
```

You have to put in a date as well as a time - Oracle doesn't have a `TIME` datatype - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197026/oracle-time-data-type). This thread also proved helpful for final formatting of the answer using the [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-to_char/) function.

And then (to check), run:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab;
ORDER BY location, start_time, end_time, title;
```

Result:

```
TITLE           START_TIME                      END_TIME                      LOCATION
Title - abc     18-MAR-20 10.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 10.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1
Title - def     18-MAR-20 10.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 10.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1
Title - abc     18-MAR-20 11.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 11.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1
Title - def     18-MAR-20 11.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 11.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1
Title - ghi     18-MAR-20 12.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 12.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1
Title - jkl     18-MAR-20 01.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 01.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1
Title - mno     18-MAR-20 02.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 02.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1
```

We can see that `abc` and `def` overlap at 10:00 and 11:00.

### FIRST_VALUE()

In the fiddle there is a first attempt which shows my train of thought - not included here.

The query:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  FIRST_VALUE (t.title) OVER (PARTITION BY t.start_time ORDER BY t.start_time ASC) AS title,
  TO_CHAR(t.start_time, 'HH24:MI') AS "start",  -- be careful, both "start" and "end" 
  TO_CHAR(t.end_time,   'HH24:MI') AS "end",     -- SQL keywords - fails if not quoted!
  t.location
FROM my_tab t
-- can have ORDER BY 2, 1, but I think actual names are more legible!
-- Again, the SQL keyword "start" must be quoted!
ORDER BY "start", title;
```

Result:

```
TITLE           start     end   LOCATION
Title - abc     10:00   10:30       Loc1
Title - abc     11:00   11:30       Loc1
Title - ghi     12:00   12:30       Loc1
Title - jkl     13:00   13:30       Loc1
Title - mno     14:00   14:30       Loc1
```

Et voilà - the desired result. If you want to eliminate `abc` instead of removing `abc`, you can use the `LAST_VALUE()` function or change the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause of the query (shown in the fiddle - not included here).

### ROW_NUMBER()

I'll run the inner query of my final query first so that my train of thought can be easily followed:

```
SELECT 
  m.title,
  m.start_time,
  m.end_time,
  m.location,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.location, m.start_time ORDER BY m.title, m.start_time, m.location) AS rn
FROM my_tab m;
```

Result:

```
TITLE           START_TIME                      END_TIME                     LOCATION  RN
Title - abc     18-MAR-20 10.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 10.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1    1
Title - def     18-MAR-20 10.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 10.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1    2
Title - abc     18-MAR-20 11.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 11.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1    1
Title - def     18-MAR-20 11.00.00.000000 AM    18-MAR-20 11.30.00.000000 AM    Loc1    2
Title - ghi     18-MAR-20 12.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 12.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1    1
Title - jkl     18-MAR-20 01.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 01.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1    1
Title - mno     18-MAR-20 02.00.00.000000 PM    18-MAR-20 02.30.00.000000 PM    Loc1    1
```

We can see that we want to hold on to the records where `rn = 1`, so we wrap this in another query (since we can't put Analytic functions in `WHERE` clauses).

So, we run the following:

```
SELECT 
  t.title, 
  TO_CHAR(t.start_time, 'HH24:MI') AS "start",  -- be careful, both "start" and end are
  TO_CHAR(t.end_time,   'HH24:MI') AS "end",    -- SQL keywords - fails if not quoted!
  t.location
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    m.title,
    m.start_time,
    m.end_time,
    m.location,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.location, m.start_time ORDER BY m.title, m.start_time, m.location) AS rn
  FROM my_tab m
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY t.title, t.location, t.start_time;
```

Result:

```
      TITLE     start     end  LOCATION
Title - abc     10:00   10:30      Loc1
Title - abc     11:00   11:30      Loc1
Title - ghi     12:00   12:30      Loc1
Title - jkl     13:00   13:30      Loc1
Title - mno     14:00   14:30      Loc1
```

Et voilà encore - the desired result again. If you have a preference for one `title` over another, you can vary the `ORDER BY` clause in the `OVER` part of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Analytic (aka Window) functions are very powerful and will repay (many, many times over) any effort you put into learning them! As previously mentioned, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on) proved very helpful.

For future reference, henceforth, could you please include your table structure(s) as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (f1 t1,....);`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (v1, v2...);`)? It's a help to have a single point of truth for the data and saves duplication of effort!

p.s. welcome to the forum!